# Ranking notices ties but does not skip appropriate ranks afterwards

Tags: mysql, rank

I was hoping not to have to post on here but I've been Googling all day with no avail. I've got some code to rank the records in my table and the format I'm after is 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 8. The code I have manages to notice a tied record on the first two records that are equal but then ignores the third. It also doesn't skip correctly. So, for example if the first 3 records are identical it ranks them 1, 1, 2. This is the code I have, I've only been using MySQL sporadically for about 7 months so no doubt it's not perfect:

```
    <?php

    $year = "$_POST[year]";
    $gender = "$_POST[gender]";
    $age = "$_POST[age]";
    $event = "$_POST[event]";

    // Formulate Query
    $query = sprintf("SELECT CONCAT(athletes.firstname,' ',athletes.lastname) AS athletename, athletes.athleteid, events.eventid, events.eventname, events.eventcode, meetings.meetingid, meetings.meetingname, meetings.location, meetings.meetingdate, meetings.year, DATE_FORMAT(meetings.meetingdate,'%%d %%b %%Y') AS date, results.performance, results.performance, results.eventid, agegroups.agegroupid, agegroups.agegroup 
    FROM results 
    JOIN athletes ON athletes.athleteid = results.athleteid
    JOIN meetings ON meetings.meetingid = results.meetingid
    JOIN events ON events.eventid = results.eventid
    JOIN agegroups ON agegroups.agegroupid = results.agegroupid
    WHERE results.performance = ANY (SELECT MIN(results.performance) FROM results WHERE meetings.year LIKE '%s' AND athletes.gender LIKE '%s' AND agegroups.agegroup LIKE '%s' AND results.eventid='%s'GROUP BY results.athleteid) ORDER BY results.performance asc
    ",
mysql_real_escape_string($year),
    mysql_real_escape_string($gender),
mysql_real_escape_string($age),
    mysql_real_escape_string($event));

    // Perform Query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // Check result
    if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
    }

    // HTML for ranking table
  echo "<table width='100%' border='0'>";
    echo "<tr><th width='25%' align='left'>Name</th>";
    echo "<th width='10%' align='left'>Perf</th>";
    echo "<th width='10%' align='left'>Age</th>";
    echo "<th width='45%' align='left'>Meeting</th>";
    echo "<th width='15%' align='right'>Date</th></tr>";
    // Use result
    $rank = $prevScore = 0; while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {     
    if ($row['performance'] > $prevScore) $rank++;     
    $prevScore = $row['performance'];   
    echo "<table valign='top' border='0' width='100%'>";
echo "<tr><td width='25%'> <a href='profile.php?id=$row[athleteid]'> $row[athletename] </a> </td>";
    echo "<td width='10%'> $rank </td>";
    echo "<td width='10%'> $row[performance] </td>";
    echo "<td width='10%'> $row[agegroup] </td>";
echo "<td width='45%'> <a href='meeting.php?id=$row[meetingid]'> $row[meetingname] </a></td>";
    echo "<td width='15%' align='right'> $row[date] </td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";

    // Free the resources associated with the result set
    mysql_free_result($result);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize two variables before your loop to track the `$naive_rank`, and the `$aware_rank` then replace

```
if ($row['performance'] > $prevScore) $rank++;
```

with

```
$naive_rank++; // always increment
if ($row['performance'] > $prevScore) {
    //whenever a non-tie occurs the aware rank catches up
    $aware_rank = $naive_rank;
    $rank = $naive_rank;
} else {
    //whenever a tie occurs, just use the old aware rank
    $rank = $aware_rank;
}
```

Comment: I initialised the $naive_rank and the $aware_rank as $naive_rank = 0; $aware_rank = 0; is this correct? Doing this gave me the order of 1, 1, 3, 4 so it did change the way it skipped, the only issue is that my top 3 records are all the same value so it should actually read 1, 1, 1, 4

Comment: I'm not sure why it won't recognize the first three are the same.  Is your performance number not an int?

Comment: No I've got it set as a varchar because it varies between time durations of 10 seconds to 2 decimal places up to 2 hours, as well as distances and points totals, depending on the event type. It's an athletics database that I'm developing so this seemed like the most appropriate way to include all the types of performance in to one column

Comment: I changed $aware_rank = -1; which gave me the correct ranking of 1, 1, 1, 4. Unfortunately though, I added another record of equal value to test it and the ranking remained as 1, 1, 1, 4 when it should have changed to 1, 1, 1, 1, 5. Is there any way of perhaps looping the $aware_rank so that it keeps subtracting 1 from the previous rank when there is a tie?

Comment: From the looks of it, `$aware_rank` should not increase unless `($row['performance'] > $prevScore)`, so the fact that it is indicates that test is errantly passing.  Are you sure your performances are **precisely** the same?  Try adding a test: `var_dump($prevScore);var_dump($row['performance']);var_dump(($row['performance'] > $prevScore));' to see if they are behaving as expected.

Comment: Ridiculous, I had a space at the end of one of my values. Once I got rid of it, it started working. Thank you very much for your time and your patience, it's greatly appreciated

Comment: You may want to convert that performance column to a float, store the number of seconds, including the two decimal places, and just adjust the display.  This adjustment would save you a variety of headaches, including the one we just resolved ;)

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason why changing MIN() to MAX() in the SELECT query and changing ($row['performance'] > $prevScore) to ($row['performance'] < $prevScore) to match the change in the query would result in the ranking order starting at 0 instead of 1? My results are currently being ranked 0, 2, 3, 4 with these alterations